# How to adjust the height of the picture element to fit the container which is responsive

Tags: html, css

Here in the below code, the width of the picture is according to the width of the container i.e the section with class `.main-content`. But the height is not according to the section. How to make the height responsive.

I have tried `height: auto` in the `.main-content` section, `max-height:100%` in the `img`, and the picture element.
When I do `max-height:100%` on the picture it adjusts according to the height of the section, but the IMG is not adjusting even when I do `max-height:100%` on the `img` element.

```css
:root{
    --clr-neutral-900: hsl(0, 0%, 8%);
    --clr-neutral-400:hsl(0, 0%, 41%);
    --clr-neutral-100:hsl(0, 0%, 98%);

    --ff-primary:'Epilogue', sans-serif;
    --ff-body: var(--ff-primary);
    --ff-heading: var(--ff-primary);

    --fw-regular:700;
    --fw-bold:500;
}

/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
  2. Remove default margin
*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*
  3. Allow percentage-based heights in the application
*/
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
/*
  Typographic tweaks!
  4. Add accessible line-height
  5. Improve text rendering
*/
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*
  6. Improve media defaults
*/
img, picture, video, canvas, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
/*
  7. Remove built-in form typography styles
*/
input, button, textarea, select {
  font: inherit;
}
/*
  8. Avoid text overflows
*/
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    gap:2rem; 
}
nav{
    width:70%;
}

.login-buttons{
    display: flex;
    gap:2rem;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 1.5rem;
    align-items: center;
}
main{
    height: 95vh;
}
header{
    height: 5vh;
}
main{
    display: flex;
}

.main-content{
    margin: 4rem;
    width:100%;
    border: solid black;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="main-content">
<div class="text">
  <h1>Make remote work</h1>
  <p>Get your team in sync, no matter your location.Streamline processes, create team rituals, and watch productivity soar. </p>
  <button>Learn more</button>
</div>
<picture>
  <source srcset="images/image-hero-desktop.png" media="(min-width:600px)">
  <img src="images/image-hero-mobile.png">
</picture>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: add an image source from google so the code snippet loads the image

Comment: The aspect ratio of the image and the aspect ratio of the container may differ. You have two options - cover which will zoom in on the image and crop either the sides or the top/bottom to make it fit or contain which will ensure the whole image is contained within the container (so either the width or the height will be the same as the container's but not necessarily both). Which do you want?